# Error from constructor when using ORMLite

Tags: android, ormlite

I have a problem: Could not find constructor that has just a (context) argument for helper class ...

```
class ORMDBHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
    private EventDAO mMyDao;

    public ORMDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        try {
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, MyClass.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource,
            int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        try {
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, MyClass.class, true);
            onCreate(db, connectionSource);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public EventDAO getEventDAO() throws SQLException {
        if (mMyDao == null) {
            mMyDao = new MyDAO(getConnectionSource(), MyClass.class);
        }

        return mMyDao;
    }

    public void clearTable(Class dataClass) throws SQLException {
        TableUtils.clearTable(getConnectionSource(), dataClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        super.close();

        mMyDao = null;
    }
}
```

Line where is error:

```
mDbHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, ORMDBHelper.class);
```

I found a few answers, but they are solution for obfuscation.

Comment: I can't quite parse this question.  Can you add more details?  Who is giving that error?  Which class is missing the constructor?

Comment: What is the error?   What class is missing which constructor?  Can you paste in the actual error?

Comment: From logcat: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find constructor that hast just a (Context) argument for helper class class ORMDBHelper

Comment: Thank you, problem was with public access to class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could not find constructor that has just a (context) argument for helper class ...

Make sure that the `ORMDBHelper` class is `public` since otherwise the class and the constructor won't be visible.

Otherwise it might be referring to a different `ORMDBHelper` class or maybe the `Context` argument is of the wrong type somehow?